# how to create png image file from the memory ？

Tags: php, image, rrdtool

I create a png image in the memory ,the code like this

```
rrdtool_function_graph(605,0,$graph_data_array)
```

when I run this

```
print rrdtool_function_graph(605,0,$graph_data_array)
```

It will show the png  image.
the question is ,how to convert it to the image file ,like abc.png ,with php?

Comment: Just open the file for writing (fopen) then write your data to it (fwrite) and close the file (fclose)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to achieve that

```
$handle = fopen('abc.png', 'w');
fwrite($handle , rrdtool_function_graph(605,0,$graph_data_array));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: thx for your advise.but when I put this(print rrdtool_function_graph(605,0,$graph_data_array)) on the php file ,it show the image in the brower.however,when I do as what you said ,it write only the 32281 in the abc.png

Comment: @SolrJ, what's "the 32281"? Also, please provide more parts of your code